# Do 'finger' and 'pinky' always show all users currently logged in?

Tags: top, finger

I've been playing around on my university's system and I noticed that sometimes the lists of logged in users I get from `finger` and `pinky` appear incomplete. For one thing, there were times when a friend sitting right next to me was logged in but I couldn't find them on the list. I checked to make sure and they were on the same exact computer (remote#) as me. Then there is the results of `top`. Sometimes it shows programs being run by users, but those users are nowhere to be found on the `pinky` list. Is there some exception where users can be logged in but not show up in `pinky`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are several commands that can answer "who is using the system" with different meanings.

If you mean interactively using the system, the commands `finger`, `pinky`, `w` and `who` will list interactive logins.  But there are several ways that will allow a user to not advertise their session, although it is not always possible to hide.

However, it is also possible to use the system in a non-interactive session, or leave background jobs on the system.   A background job doesn't necessarily require the user to stay logged in.  Commands like `top` and `ps` will list what users are running, interactive or not.   There may be a column in the output of these programs called "tty" that will be blank for processes that are not part of an interactive session.

Finally, the `last` command (I recommend something like `last -20` or `last | less` for busy systems) will show you who recently used the system and if they are still logged in.

And for extra fun, some systems may have enabled commands like `talk` and `write` which are precursors to today's instant messaging.

Comment: Thanks! That `last` command is really fascinating! Where can I learn more of these interesting Linux commands?

Comment: Each of these has a man page (type `man last` for instance).  At the end of the man page, it lists other man pages for additional information.